# Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function() {return uuid;}

Tags: javascript, requirejs, mismatch, requirejs-optimizer, requirejs-define

I have installed pinata SDK using

```
npm install --save @pinata/sdk
```

I’m implementing the code to add files to IPFS using pinata

```
const pinataSDK= require('@pinata/sdk');
const pinata = pinataSDK('812f8a2d416d9be9afea',  '668516ac85834685ed785bcaec839f5ad1aeca099788cd8aa814ccdbad77d1bb');
    console.log("entered");
pinata.testAuthentication().then((result) => {
    //handle successful authentication here
    console.log(result);
}).catch((err) => {
    //handle error here
    console.log(err);
});

const fs = require('fs');
const readableStreamForFile = fs.createReadStream('./naruto6.jpeg');
const options = {
    pinataMetadata: {
        name: MyCustomName,
        keyvalues: {
            customKey: 'customValue',
            customKey2: 'customValue2'
        }
    },
    pinataOptions: {
        cidVersion: 0
    }
};
pinata.pinFileToIPFS(readableStreamForFile, options).then((result) => {
    //handle results here
    console.log(result);
}).catch((err) => {
    //handle error here
    console.log(err);
});
```

I’m facing the following error.

https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded

https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch
[image]

I have installed the require.js node module. I could not understand the error properly. I'm new to js. Please help me out.

Comment: This will not work as your code tried to use require function from NodeJS (server side - CommonJS modules) but the browser has RequireJS which uses different module format - AMD. More here https://requirejs.org/docs/commonjs.html

Comment: I have used AMD format the first error is gone. but still, I'm getting the second error.    Is there any other way than using require? Pls help me out

Comment: Did you mean the error regarding uuid?